# having file names and delete them

Tags: c++, file, stream, io

I want to have access to all files of a folder and have a list of them and work with them.
For example: there is a folder named `"new folder`" and consist of files : `1.txt` and `2.txt`
I don't know what are in the folder `new folder`. So I want a list of files in it .
Hence the questions are :
 1- How can I have such this list?
 2- How can I delete a file (e.g 2.txt) whether i know there is file with this name or not.
 3- Is it possible to figure out has a txt file been used or not (whether it is empty or not)
thanks;

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I checke all func' i thought might be useful.

Comment: For Linux: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sys/stat.h and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Boost [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.html) to analyze folder content, and [remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) to delete the file. You will find in filesystem [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html) some sample that will ease your work.

*edit*: [remove](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#remove)(path) it's available in boost filesystem.

Comment: Worth noting though that: "The remove function causes the file whose name is the string pointed to by filename to be no longer accessible by that name" (C11 final draft N1570 7.21.4.1.2), which is not quite the same as actually deleting it, and open-std.org says: "The behavior for file types other than regular files is unspecified." http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG15/docs/rr/9945-1/9945-1-59.html, so `remove()` may not be as good as something platform specific.

Comment: Hmmm... another page says: "If path does not name a directory, remove(path) shall be equivalent to unlink(path).
If path names a directory, remove(path) shall be equivalent to rmdir(path)." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/remove.html
Not entirely sure where that leaves us (with respect to Posix systems).

Comment: @BobTFish: I hope that what's happening when issuing such calls will be what we *logically* expect, modulo such complicated issues like *race conditions* and the like...